# Partial FPGA reconfiguration and performance

Tags: real-time, fpga

These questions may sound very esoteric to most, but I'd really like to know more about this stuff.

### 1st

I'm wondering how long does it take for an FPGA to reconfigure itself, from the time its modelled circuit is powered down to the time a new one is in place and operational.

I am aware that Place-&-Route is a costly process, but that is because the P&R tools must *decide where to put* the components and *how to route* them.

Consider that P&R analysis is done, and all that's left is actually reconfiguring the FPGA: is that a slow process by itself? Can it be done hundreds or thousands of times per second?

There are several implications for such a possibility that I'm curious about. To name 2, it could allow us to serve an FPGA to multiple concurrent "clients" (the same way a GPU is capable of rendering stuff for multiple different programs), or provide for extremely fine-tuned circuits for long number-crunching processes of well-defined but numerous processing stages of highly asynchronous processing (think: complex Haskell programs).

### 2nd

Anothing thing I'd like to ask is whether an FPGA can be partially reconfigured in realtime, while the modelled circuit is powered and operational, as long as the parts being reconfigured are powered off, of course.

Several interesting implications would arise from such a possibility as well, for example allowing for realtime reconfigurable buses, hardware emulation of neural networks, etc.

Are such things being extensively researched right now? And how likely are they to be researched in the future?

Comment: Looks like partial FPGA reconfiguration is possible, yes. I should have researched more before asking (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_re-configuration). That's also a duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387921/how-are-fpgas-updated). However, the 1st question stands still.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to re-configure anything 100s of thousands of times? FPGA is not GPU, and you don't need to perform P&R before partial reconfiguration, how it works is that you prepare your IPs that you want to reconfigure, you create multiple version of it for different scenario, then load them into the FPGA whenever they are needed. It takes seconds, not micro-seconds to do so.

Comment: Maybe these articles can be helpful: http://www12.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/publications/pub2010/OWTK10.pdf , http://www.eetimes.com/design/programmable-logic/4014808/How-to-take-advantage-of-partial-reconfiguration-in-FPGA-designs

Comment: damage, thanks for the articles. FarhadA, you could answer this question with that information (about reconfiguration taking seconds), but please provide a reference link for it. I know FPGAs are not designed to be used like that, I'm just wondering whether they can or cannot, whether nobody thinks it would be useful, and whether anyone is working on it right now.

Comment: this also: http://halcyon.usc.edu/~pk/prasannawebsite/papers/sidhuFPL99.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reconfiguration time depends on a lot of things.  The big ones are

- how much of the FPGA you are reconfiguring (how many bits need to go in)
- How fast you can get the data in (using quad-SPI seems to be the favoured way of bringing FPGAs up fast nowadays)

Big FPGAs can be many 10s to 100s of milliseconds to completely reconfigure.

A small configuration can be achieved within the PCI express startup time (100ms IIRC) in order to enable a pure FPGA card to be enumerated in time and then the rest of the config can be loaded later.

In terms of very dynamic reconfiguration, its more likely that the bottle neck is swapping the various data sets in and out that go with each bitstream - I imagine anything which needs a lot of FPGA to accelerate it is a pretty large dataset... but you might have other applications in mind?

Comment: BTW, quad-SPI is the popular new-faster-than-traditional-SPI method but still low pin count for low-cost, small-package configuration memories. However, really fast configuration is and has pretty much always been done with large 8-bit or 16-bit parallel FLASH chips or via custom direct configuration access (e.g. via Xilinx's FPGAs' SelectMAP port).

Comment: It's just a random idea that occurred me. I have no specific application in mind. In fact, I don't use FPGAs, they just fascinate me. I'm not thinking about them because I need to process large datasets, but because I think they might be a solution to the parallelism needs of the future. I think maybe GPGPU will be too limited to run a Haskell program efficiently, so FPGAs are the only other solution I know besides multicore CPUs.